# How to change "It's" to "It is" (without apostrophe) using str_replace?

Tags: replace, preg-replace, str-replace, apostrophe, apostrophe-cms

I want to replace from Facebook's relationships string "It's complicated" to other text.

The line is like this:

```
$user->relationship = str_replace(array('single', 'It's complicated'), array('Soltero(a)', 'Es complicado'),$data['relationship_status']);
```

Using: `'It's complicated' , 'It&apos;s complicated' or 'It&#39;s complicated'`  ,
do not work.

Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use literal single quoted character ('), you have to escape them.

like:

```
$str = '\''; // single quote
```

You could try this.

```
$user->relationship = str_replace(array('single', 'It\'s complicated'), array('Soltero(a)', 'Es complicado'),$data['relationship_status']);
```

The PHP could not recognize the single literal quoted character (') without escape sequences character. Here is the explanation about it:
[Strings literal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

It's also happen for double literal quoted character (").

Comment: Thanks [azisfatoni](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1455117/azisfatoni)! Now, **it's** working! :)

Comment: Great..with my pleasure. (y)

Comment: Please remove the apostrophe-cms tag as it doesn't apply to this question. Thanks!